# Choosing in Pivot Filter Current Month

Tags: filter, pivot

I'm trying to code so that one of the pivot filter the current month. But it's giving me an error

Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
Dim Lmonth As Integer
    Lmonth = Month(Worksheets("Cash Receipts").Range("A1").Value)

'
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[Date].[Month].[Month]"). _
        VisibleItemsList = Array("[Date].[Month].&[2018-]&Lmonth&[-01T00:00:00]")
End Sub

Please help.